# How to avoid docker-compose recreating a running container?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-machine

I have a docker compose file

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  service1:
    image: serv1image
    container_name: service1
    networks:
      - local
    depends_on:
      - service2
      - service3
  service2:
    image: serv2image
    container_name: service2
    networks:
      - local
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  service3:
    image: serv3image
    container_name: service3
    networks:
      - local
    ports:
      - "2000:2000"
  service4:
    image: serv4image
    container_name: service4
    networks:
      - local
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    depends_on:
      - service2
      - service3
networks:
  local-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: local
```

I intially started service1 using

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up --no-recreate -d service1
```

Obviously it started service 1 and also booted up service2 and service 3 as they are it's dependencies.
Now I had to start the service4 at a later stage of time. I started it using the following command.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up  --no-recreate -d service4
```

But unfortunately this also tried to recreate the service 2 and service3 as they are its dependencies irrespective of mentioning --no-recreate flag and I got conflict error too stating

**Cannot create container for service service4: Conflict. The container name "service2" is already in use by container**

Why this is happening and is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Did you run both `docker-compose` commands from the same directory?  That behavior sounds like Compose isn't finding the existing containers, maybe it believes it's in a different Compose "project".  (Deleting the `container_name:` lines is safe and will avoid this specific problem, but I suspect you'll wind up with two copies of the containers.)

Comment: Did you try starting without the `-f docker-compose.yaml`, as this is the default filename this is not needed to add it to the command. Also, the example contains a typo `container_nam` instead of `container_name`. Was this by accident creating the example, or is this typo also in your real code? And can you maybe add the output of `docker-compose ps` after the first command?

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1397 you can use --no-deps option to avoid recreating other dependent services.eg:
docker-compose up -d --no-deps service1